# Angular strips web components from rendered components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-component, angular-elements

According to [this tutorial](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/using-web-components-in-angular) we need to set the `tsconfig.json` compiler option `allowJs` to `true` and include `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` and I've done these two things as shown in this Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-web-component-stripping

I also created a minimal reproduction using the latest Angular version here:

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/scully-custom-element-test

In the Stackblitz demo the `innerHTML` of the `hello` component is set to:

```
  <h1> Web Component Test</h1>
  <fs-image url="https://fireflysemantics.github.io/i/developer/instant-html-vscode.png"></fs-image>
```

However Angular strips the `fs-image` web component.  What do we need to do to include it?

Angular does log this warning:

> WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see https://g.co/ng/security#xss

Comment: Did you import the custom element?

Comment: The custom element is included via CDN like like this: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@fireflysemantics/fs-image"></script>`

Comment: You could try to run the html through the safeHtml sanitizer in Angular? https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer